# Java - BufferedReader Stalls without an Escape Character

Tags: java, server, bufferedreader

I am building a server in Java, and the input feed is giving me trouble - its current setup cannot read more than one line, and it cannot read anything without "\n" at the end.  Here is the current input loop:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverConnection.getInputStream()));

    if(input.ready()){

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String line;


        while((line = input.readLine()) != null){

            text.append(line);
            System.out.println(line);

        }

        sentData = text.toString();
        return true;
    }
```

My current loop using a BufferedReader cannot read more than one line of incoming data, and if there is no newline character, a timeout exception is thrown (I programmed it to do that), and the data is not read at all.  It is, of course, unacceptable to have a listener that can only see one line of data, and stalls when the sent data is not formatted properly.

So I am looking for a method that allows the program to read any number of lines, and for the program to stop reading when it has reached the end of the data stream (even without a new line).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read from the `InputStream` directly into the `StringBuilder`. `readLine()` of `BufferedReader` will wait for `\r` or `\n` character. This looks like stalling.

```
int ch;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while((ch = serverConnection.getInputStream().read())!= -1) { // -1 will be read at EOS
    text.append((char)ch);
}
sentData = text.toString();
return true;
```

### Update

The following piece of code is to demonstrate the difference between usage of `BufferedReader` and `InputStream` to read bytes and what is available to the user during read operation. `BufferedReader` will always give you lines which are either terminated by line breaks or by EOS. Whereas `InputStream` will make the available bytes to the user.

In scenarios where it is *NOT* necessary to close the streams, and the bytes transferred has it's own way to mark start and end of packets/messages, you will be using `InputStream` to read bytes. If you try using `BufferedReader` for these applications, the last line of the message will be made available once the server receives the next packet/message, unless you send each line with a line-break.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Thread(new BufferedReaderServer()).start();
        new Thread(new InputStreamServer()).start();
        final String requestString = "Line#1\nLine#2";

        System.out.println("\nSending to BufferedReaderServer");
        Socket clientSocket1 = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost()
                .getHostAddress(), 8003);
        OutputStream outputStream1 = clientSocket1.getOutputStream();
        outputStream1.write(requestString.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        outputStream1.close();
        clientSocket1.close();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("\nSending to InputStreamServer");

        Socket clientSocket2 = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost()
                .getHostAddress(), 8004);
        OutputStream outputStream2 = clientSocket2.getOutputStream();
        outputStream2.write(requestString.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        outputStream2.close();
        clientSocket2.close();
    }

    static class BufferedReaderServer implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8003);
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String s = null;
                System.out.println("BufferedReaderServer read START");
                while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                System.out.println("BufferedReaderServer read END");
                socket.getInputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class InputStreamServer implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8004);
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("InputStreamServer read START");
                int ch;
                while ((ch = socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) ch);
                }
                System.out.println("\nInputStreamServer read END");
                socket.getInputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***The issue what is being faced here could be due to non-closing of client socket. Depends on the user's application***

Comment: The effect is identical except that this code will preserve the line terminators.

Comment: @EJP, the effect might be the same but what the user has in the StringBuilder is different.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The read() method never returned -1, but I used the setSoTimeout method in combination with your answer to stop the loop when the stream was finished being read.

Comment: @IrregularSquare, do you have the client code? If so, is it closing the output stream?

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing away every odd-numbered line. Remove the `readLine()` inside the loop.